# 'AddRange' is not a member of... (while i attempt to save column order of a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to save and load the data grid view column order.

I'm using this code that i suppose is also right.

```
 Private Sub SaveColumnOrder()
    Dim upperBound As Integer = Me.DataTable1DataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
    Dim columnIndexes(upperBound) As String

    For index As Integer = 0 To upperBound
        Dim column As DataGridViewColumn = Me.DataTable1DataGridView.Columns(index)

        columnIndexes(column.DisplayIndex) = index.ToString()
    Next

    My.Settings.GridColumnIndexes = New StringCollection
    My.Settings.GridColumnIndexes.AddRange(columnIndexes)
End Sub

Private Sub LoadColumnOrder()
    Dim columnIndexes As StringCollection = My.Settings.GridColumnIndexes

    For displayIndex As Integer = 0 To columnIndexes.Count - 1
        Dim index As Integer = CInt(columnIndexes(displayIndex))

        Me.DataTable1DataGridView.Columns(index).DisplayIndex = displayIndex
    Next
End Sub
```

Problem is that i don't know how to set the GridColumnIndexes inside project property settings.
I set to string and other "data" options but i always get the error: 'AddRange' is not a member of... {option selected}

Which is the right option in settings to make it finally work? Thank you :)

Comment: Is this the code that gives you that error?

Comment: Basically is not the code that gives the error. Is the settings option i set under project property. I set GridColumnIndexes as string in the project property. http://s27.postimg.org/kbzkhnipv/screenshot_3.png - To fix i should know which type i should set for GridColumnIndexes in the combobox as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: why create that temp array instead of doing `My.Settings.GridColumnIndexes.Add(index.ToString())` ?  Have you tried that?

Comment: let me try Plutonix :)

Comment: it doesn't work. i also noticed that "StringCollection" can't be converted as a string.

Comment: the comment image shows the Setting is `String` not `StringCollection` (the fullname is `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`.  The Setting Type and the Type you are using in code are different.  Change Settings to a StringCollection

Comment: YEAH! That is what i need and it works greatly!!!!!!! System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection - THANKS :)

Comment: I would add. Is there a feature to also reset the order back?